# Calling parallel ssh (pssh) in bash script

Tags: linux, ssh, shell-script

I can run commands in parallel on a list of machines using `pssh`command. For instance to make a folder `foo` on several machines, listed in `hosts.txt` I can run:

```
pssh -h hosts.txt -l MyUserName "mkdir foo"
```

But since the command requires more arguments (i.e. using public key for authentication, etc) I tried to create the following bash script `bar.sh`, such that the command I want to run is simply given as the argument to the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pssh -h hosts.txt -l MyUserName "$@"
```

But running `bar.sh mkdir foo` freezes the terminal, even I can not kill it using Ctrl+C.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have access to pssh to try this but can you try `bar.sh 'mkdir foo'` or `bar.sh "mkdir foo"` See if those work?

Comment: Another thing you could try is use `$*` instead of `$@` See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with `pssh`. Do you get the same error if using GNU Parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash
parallel -j10 --slf hosts.txt --nonall "$@"
```

Put the username in hosts.txt:

```
myuser@host1
myuser@host2
```

Answer (score 0):

It is required to use -i (inline aggregated output and error for each server), below will work:

```
pssh -h pssh.txt -l root -i uptime
```